# Почему emmet в vscode не работает с sass?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

Почему emmet в vscode не работает с sass? С scss работает все прекрасно, а вот с sass нет. Все приходится писать вручную. Весь текст белый, т.е. не разделен по цветам, как должно быть. Читал на различных сайтах, решения так и не нашел, пробовал менять цветовую схему как советовали, тоже не помогло. Читал так-же, что vscode не работает с sass, но я думаю, что проблема не в этом, так-как у всех на том же YouTobe все прекрасно работает.
[image: Вот такой текст получается]

Comment: Попробуйте данное [расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented)

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: на здоровье. Можете написать ответ для будующих поколений. Как и что сделали, чтобы все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Ура, ответ найдет, чтобы решить эту проблему установите плагин Sass для vscode.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ ссылки - это замечательно. Но необходимо добавить основные тезисы в сам ответ на случай того, что ссылка станет не активной со временем. А ссылку использовать как источник информации